# How to trigger of the render of data that a user inputs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, render

In this App, student data is pulled from an API, new Tags can be added for each student by clicking the PLUS button on a card.

ISSUE: the tags DON’T render on the screen immediately after they are inputed. They will only render after the drop down is closed and opened again or if a number of tags are entered consecutively.

The project and code can be found here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hatch-frontend-mch-52n67?file=/src/components/views/Card.js:2280-2320

**Card.js**

```
// ...

// Submit Handler function:
const submitNewTagHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setHasTags(true);
    console.log(tags);
    setHeightState(
       `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
    setTags([...tags, newTag]);
    updateStudents(tags, index);
    setNewTag('');
  };


//Tag render:
{hasTags && <Tags student={student} />}
// Tag input:
<form onSubmit={submitNewTagHandler}>
    <input
    className='​add-tag-input​'
    onChange={(e) => setNewTag(e.target.value)}
    value={newTag}
    type='text'
    placeholder='Add a new tag'
    />
</form>
```

**App.js**

```
// updateStudent is called as update in App.js
// (This updates the main data array called students)
const update = (t, index) => {
    setTags(t);
    setStudents(
      students.map((student, i) => {
        // console.log(i, index);
        if (i === index) {
          console.log(student, tags);
          return { ...student, tags };
        } else {
          return student;
        }
      })
    );
    console.log(students);
  };
```

**Tags.js**

```
const Tags = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='tags'>
      {props.student.tags.map((tag, index) => {
        return (
          <h3 className='tag' key={index}>
            {tag}{' '}
          </h3>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I’ve tried different ways to use useEffect to re-render the tags but have been unsuccessful thus far…

Thanks!

Comment: Ok np! I'll add some code!

Comment: your <Tags> component is the one that's generating the list? Where is your tags props passed? Where's the component you talking about drop down list.

Comment: The component tree is like this: App.js > DisplayStudentInfo.js > Card.js > Tags.js

Comment: if you don't mind, since you are asking for help trouble shooting, to better label the codes, for example, the component name for each of the codes you share.

Comment: The codes looks fine, but we have to see what is the component that you are rendering. It could be caused by you not passing your props properly etc, if you don't want to share the codes then our help will be limited.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Yes, <Tags> generates the list using the map function. <Tags> receives the prop _{student}_ in Card.js. _{student}_  comes from DisplayStudentInfo.js which maps over the data array: students.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I shared my code using the CodeSandbox link. I'm open to share my code ... do you mean by posting code in the comments, editing my original post, or by other means?

Comment: posted an answer with new sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay because of how you setNewTags using local state, and then you passing props to Tags, you causing sync errors, since react states are all async.

So I updated the codes to useRef to get current values and it should work.

There's many many changes to be made. Basically your codes are all messed up because you are updating state with another state. (e.g. u updating tags with new tags), but newtags has not been updated with new value.

I've also removed your useEffect in App.js, and showed you how to useMemo instead.

Delete these 2 lines

```
  const [tags, setTags] = useState(student.tags);
  const [newTag, setNewTag] = useState('');
```

Create new input Ref

```
  const inputRef = useRef()
  const formRef = useRef()
```

Change input to this

```
       <input
          className='​add-tag-input​'
          ref = {inputRef} //add this
          //value={newTag} remove this
          type='text'
          placeholder='Add a new tag'
        />
```

then your handle submit function

```
  const submitNewTagHandler = (e) => {
    const value = inputRef.current.value
    e.preventDefault();
    setHeightState(
       `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
    updateStudents([...student.tags, value], index);
    formRef.current.reset()
  };
```

then change this line to the updated line.

{student?.tags?.length > 0 && }

Then you need to update your .map with a key else it's not rendering correctly.

```
<Card key={`student-${student.id}`} students={props.students} student={student} index={index} updateStudents={props.updateStudents} />
```

In your update function

```
const update = (t, index) => {
    setTags(t);
    setStudents((prev) =>
      prev.map((student, i) => {
        // console.log(i, index);
        if (i === index) {
          console.log("prev map", student, t);
          return { ...student, tags: t };
        } else {
          return student;
        }
      })
    );
    console.log(students);
  };
```

Update component to this

```
const Tags = ({ tags }) => {
  return (
    <div className="tags">
      {tags.map((tag, index) => {
        return (
          <h3 className="tag" key={`tag-${index}`}>
            {tag}{" "}
          </h3>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Add this to fix your accordion where input become hidden.

```
 useEffect(() => {

    if (setActive) setHeightState(`${content.current.scrollHeight}px`);

  },[props])
```

There's too many changes made. I may have missed out some of them here.
[see new sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hatch-frontend-mch-forked-rogpj?file=/src/App.js:2581-2937)

Comment: and your input box did not disappear, it just got hidden because of your accordion css -> overflow: hidden;

Comment: First off, THANK YOU so much!

Comment: A few questions... **1)** `{student?.tags?.length > 0 && }` Why put ? after student and tags?

Comment: **2)** `.filter(
        ({ tags }) =>
          tagFilter === "" ||
          tags.filter((x) => x.match(new RegExp(tagFilter, "i"))).length > 
      );` -- Why is `tagFilter === "" ||` used?  `new RegExp` create a regex out of the tagFilter and match creates an array of matched tags, correct?

Comment: student?.tag?.length is used to prevent error being thrown when student or student.tags is undefined during the first render.

Comment: 2) I added tagFilter === '' (returns true) to show all the students when there's no input for tagsFilter.

Comment: took the liberty to simplify a lot of your codes, hopefully it's helpful you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: It's very helpful!! +1! I was able to add a delete functionality for **Tags.js** `onst Tags = ({ tags, deleteTag, studentIndex }) => {
  //The Index of the Tag to be deleted is passed to deleteTag in App.js 
  const deleteTagHandler = (index) => {
    const tagIndex = index;
    deleteTag(studentIndex, tagIndex);
  };`

Comment: And I passed that to **App.js** `const deleteTag = (studentIndex, tagIndex) => {
    console.log('tag', tagIndex, 'is deleted for student', studentIndex) 
    setStudents(
      students.map((student, i) => {
        if (i === studentIndex) {
          const {tags} = student;
          const updatedTags = tags.slice(0, tagIndex).concat(tags.slice(tagIndex + 1, tags.length))
          return {...student, tags:updatedTags}
        } else {
          return student
        }
        
      })
    )
      
  }`

Comment: please create a separate question or sand box, i cannot read the codes in comment like that.

Comment: delete tag sshould be something like    tags.filter( item => item.index !== deleteIndex)

Comment: I've linked a new sandbox that contains the delete ability inside Tag.js and App.js https://codesandbox.io/s/33i01